# Change working directory after starting remote session

Tags: powershell

I don't know if I'm just overthinking this, but I can't figure out how to automate the change of the working directory once starting a session on remote computer. I'm trying to automate this, so I can child-item a list of the files in that directory, speed up the process of running something from that working directory.

```
Clear-Host
$computer = Read-Host "enter remote computer name"
$softwareServer = "\\servername\software"

cd $softwareServer
Get-ChildItem .\ | Format-Table Name
$software = Read-Host "enter software name"

$softwarePath = "$softwareServer\$software"
$softwareDestination = "\\$computer\c$\software\$software"

mkdir \\$computer\c$\software\$software
robocopy $softwarePath $softwareDestination /MIR

Enter-PSSession -Computer $computer

"trying to automate change of working directory here to c:\software\$software"
```

I have tried the following commands after the session with the remote computer has started, but I'm not having any luck with them...

cd c:\software$using:software

and

Set-Location -Path "c:\software$using:$software"

both have done nothing in the script. The script works fine up to the point of entering the session... it just is not changing to the new working path as im attempting to do... because once i figure out how to set the new working path, i want to get-childitem the software directory to see what the install files are, so i can know which file to run for the install process.....

Comment: Did you try Fullname instead of Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface**:

- The the purpose of **[`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession)** is to **enter an *interactive* session.**
- Due to a *bug* - see [GitHub issue #16350](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16350)- trying to do so ***from a script*** - in an attempt to let the user take over for a while until they exit the remote session themselves - **only works if the `Enter-PSSession` call is *the very last statement* in the script** and if the script itself was called from an interactive session.

---

As of PowerShell (Core) v7.4.0, there is ***no* mechanism to preset the current location (working directory)** for an interactive session entered with `Enter-PSSession`.

- The [`New-PSSessionOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption) cmdlet has no parameter to that effect, and neither does `Enter-PSSession` itself.

Therefore, your **only option** is to:

- Create a session object *explicitly*, using [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession) and use it as the `-Session` argument in subsequent calls.
- In order to preset the current location, call [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) first, then `Enter-PSSession`.

```
# Create a session object.
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer

# Use it with Invoke-Command to preset the current location.
Invoke-Command -Session $session { Set-Location C:\software\$using:software }

# Then enter the session interactively.
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
```

Comment: Thank you, that information gave me what i needed to finish the script. Unfortunately i couldn't set the location to a directory with variable... im not sure if there is something i could do to make it work... but a simple second line with cd .\$using:software worked... thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it, @IT4Gov; `Set-Location C:\software\$using:software` should work (assuming that the `C:\software` part is correct), just like `cd .\$using:software` (`cd` is just an alias of `Set-Location`; you could enclose the argument in `"..."`, but that isn't strictly necessary). Note that you can help future readers by clearly signaling which answer, if any, solved your problem, namely by [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248777) it.